# How to write array elements to a file one per each line in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, bash-completion

I have an array in `arr` which contains list of strings - `(string1 string2 string3 ...)`

How do I append these elements to a text file one element per line.

The elements could be of any data type.  But I need to write those elements one per each line like:

```
string1
string2
string3
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" > new_file
```